# is It safe to use feature activated method to create new site column which is used then by content type

Tags: feature-receiver

We have a content type vs project. The content type is adding a field ref. This field ref is a new site column created using same project but as an empty element.

This works.

I am wondering whether we can use the feature activated or feature installing event receiver of the content type feature to create this site column and feature uninstalling or feature deactivated to delete this site column.

Which is advisable?

Answer (score 2):

The problem you would have is timing, the field must have been created before you provision your content type. So the FeatureActivated is a no go. I would not go for FeatureInstalling either since you can not control with ease the execution order.

I sometimes uses the FeatureActivated event, but in those cases I create both content type, fields, and binds to list with c# code (no XML)

Comment: I concur, one or the other, not both. Either do it all in code, or all in XML.